# Make filter appear from the left to right side

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to apply a filter on an image to make a transition from gray to color from the left to the right side. For the moment, I only have the filter applied on all the image at the same time.

Is it possible by using css ?

This is a little [reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-jones-rn80u?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:0-346)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here you go...**

```css
.img {
  width: 340px;
  display: block;
}

.filter {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filter:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: from_left 1s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  background: linear-gradient(gray, gray);
}

@keyframes from_left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='filter'>
    <img class='img' src='https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg' alt='Bridge'>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```